# Expected value of a random function

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation

Assume $r>0$ is a variable (not random) but $X(r)$ is a random variable (like the total number of points randomly distributed over a plane in a circle of radius $r$). We know that for all $r$ (no matter how large):

$$E[X(r)]\leq 2$$

Under what conditions we can conclude?:

$$E\left[\lim\limits_{r \to \infty}X(r)\right]\leq 2$$

Comment: Does $E[X(+\infty)]$ mean $\lim_{r\to\infty} E[X(r)]$ or $E[\lim_{r\to\infty}X(r)]$?

Comment: @Dfrtbx Thank you. Yes, I corrected the statement.

Comment: the basic theory of limits tells you that $\lim_{r\to \infty} E(X_r) \leq 2$ and sufficient regularity of $X_r : \Omega \times (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ will allow you to interchange the expectation and the limit.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 can you tell more what does sufficient regularity mean?

Comment: @Su20200 one is allowed to write $\lim E(X_r)=E(\lim X_r)$ when $X_r$ is “nice” enough, or regular, i.e. satisfies, for example, the hypotheses of the *monotone convergence theorem* (for integrals) or the *dominated convergence theorem* and these two are probably the most used theorems to justify interchange of expectation and limits, however, they do not exhaust all cases.

Answer (score 1):

If $X(r)$ satisfies the requirements of any of the following three theorems then you can exchange the limit and expectation:

- [Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)
- [Bounded Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem#Bounded_convergence_theorem)
- [Monotone Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral)

You have that $E[X(r)]\leq 2 \hspace{2mm} \forall r \in \mathbb{R}^+$, then it's true of the limit too: $\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}E[X(r)]\leq2$

To complete the proof you just need to use one of those previous three theorems to permit yourself to exchange the limit and expectation.

**EDIT**
A usually pretty convenient way to do this is to re-express the expectation as the integral of probabilities:

\begin{equation}
E[X(r)] = \int_{-\infty}^0(1-P[X(r)\geq x])dx +  \int_{0}^\infty P[X(r)\geq x]dx
\end{equation}

Note that the two functions $(1-P[X(r)\geq x])$ and $P[X(r)\geq x]$ are bounded above by 2 for all $x$, thus you can use the Dominated Convergence Theorem to exchange the integrals and limits:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} E[X(r)] = \int_{-\infty}^0 \lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}(1-P[X(r)\geq x])dx +  \int_{0}^\infty \lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}P[X(r)\geq x]dx
\end{equation}

The previous functions are almost surely continuous in $X(r)$, so using the [Continuous Mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem):
\begin{equation}
\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty} E[X(r)] = \int_{-\infty}^0 (1-P[X^*\geq x])dx +  \int_{0}^\infty P[X^*\geq x]dx = E[X^*]
\end{equation}

Where $X^* = \lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}X(r)$

Comment: cool edit. i removed then put back my upvote